# MYSQL multiple join error and learning

Tags: php, mysql

I appreciate your patience as I am still trying to learn joining tables.  I have in the past done joins between two tables, and I would nest them in the php code which I am sure is incorrect and very inefficient.  I would like to learn the "right" way.

Here is my query so far.  I am getting an error: unknown column in on clause

```
SELECT PermissionID FROM Permissions 
INNER JOIN PermissionsAssigned ON Permissions.PermissionID = PermissionsAssigned.PermissionID
INNER JOIN Roles ON PermissionsAssigned.RoleID = Roles.RoleID
INNER JOIN RolesAssigned ON Roles.RoleID = RolesAssigned.RoleID
INNER JOIN UserDirectory ON RolesAssigned.UserID = UserDirectory.UserID
WHERE UserDirectory.UserID = 4

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Permissions` (
  `PermissionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PermissionID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`PermissionID`),
  KEY `Index 1` (`PermissionID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PermissionsAssigned` (
  `PermissionsAssignedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Permission ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RoleID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PermissionsAssignedID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PermissionsAssignedID_UNIQUE` (`PermissionsAssignedID`),
  KEY `FK_PermissionsAssigned_Permissions` (`Permission ID`),
  KEY `FK_PermissionsAssigned_Roles` (`RoleID`),
  KEY `Index 1` (`PermissionsAssignedID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PermissionsAssigned_Permissions` FOREIGN KEY (`Permission ID`) REFERENCES `Permissions` (`PermissionID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PermissionsAssigned_Roles` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleID`) REFERENCES `Roles` (`RoleID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Roles` (
  `RoleID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RoleID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`RoleID`),
  KEY `Index 1` (`RoleID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RolesAssigned` (
  `RoleAssignedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RoleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RoleAssignedID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`RoleAssignedID`),
  KEY `Index 1` (`RoleAssignedID`),
  KEY `FK_RolesAssigned_UserDirectory` (`UserID`),
  KEY `FK_RolesAssigned_Roles` (`RoleID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_RolesAssigned_Roles` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleID`) REFERENCES `Roles` (`RoleID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_RolesAssigned_UserDirectory` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `UserDirectory` (`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserDirectory` (
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserID_UNIQUE` (`UserID`),
  KEY `Index 1` (`UserID`),
  KEY `FK_UserDirectory_Departments` (`DepartmentID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_UserDirectory_Departments` FOREIGN KEY (`DepartmentID`) REFERENCES `Departments` (`DepartmentID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks!
Matthew

Comment: If you're getting an unknown column then you're asking for an unknown column. What is the *exact* error?

Comment: post some info about your tables

Comment: Unknown column PermissionsAssigned.PermissionID in on clause

Comment: I edited the post with the table structure.

Comment: PermissionsAssigned table does not contain PermissionID Columns , its simple :)

Comment: In your table structure , Can you see `Permission ID int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',` Here there is space Not a whole word `PermissionID` ??

Comment: Ohh for goodness sake.   My head hurts bad enough now a dumb thing like that.  Thank you for the help...

Comment: your sql create table set is not complete, there is no definition of `Departments` table, so I cant create sqlfiddle to test :-)

Comment: Issue resolved, and the above query worked fine once the space was removed from the actual table.  I shortened the create statements thinking not all of the fields were needed.   It all came down to a space error on my end and it took a different set of eyes to tell me I was off.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Matthew23 Hi you can Accept answer I posted as it solves your issue and I answered it before anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PermissionsAssigned` (
  `PermissionsAssignedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ***`Permission ID`*** int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

***HERE is the problem***
change Permission ID to PermissionID in you database

Answer (score 0):

You need to make table definition proper like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PermissionsAssigned` (
  `PermissionsAssignedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PermissionID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'`, .................
```

`PermissionID` should be a Whole word . Check in your Code its having space.